# How to make linux to reboot every day?

Tags: linux, cron

I tried to use cron but I don't see it reboots - no one program restarts.

I wrote to my crontab -e

```
48  8   *   *  *   sudo reboot
```

I tried to make it reboot every day at 8:48. Why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sudo? Try without sudo in root crontab.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo crontab -e` and include "/sbin/" on your command "reboot.

```
48  8   *   *  *   /sbin/reboot
```